# Why my NavigationDrawer width is smaller than the other apps?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I've read thousands of articles and other stackoverflow questions but I really can't understand why my Navigation Drawer is smaller than the other apps.

This is currently my Navigation Drawer following Google guidelines:
[image: My Navigation Drawer]

And I want it to be like this:
[image: Other Navigation Drawers]

(Please note how the Drawer in Google Drive covers a big part of the FAB)

Hardcoding `android:maxWidth="320dp"` (for both phones and tablets) I can achieve this:
[image: My Navigation Drawer with hardcoded maxWidth]

That is ALMOST what I want, but it doesn't follow Google guidelines and it's still a bit smaller than other Navigation Drawers.

In addition to the FAB, you can also notice the difference by looking at the status bar.

Here's my home screen:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- My content -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my NavigationView layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/color_selector_drawer_text"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_selector_drawer_icon" />
```

What should I change to make it as other Navigation Drawers?

Comment: Exact same thing here. Have you found anything?

Comment: @BehnamMabodi nope, nothing :(

Answer (score 4):

Ok , i found the answer.
According to [Navigation drawer pattern](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) "The maximum width of the nav drawer is 280dp on mobile and 320dp on tablet" so default width of nav drawer in our apps is what it meant to be, but other apps are using 320dp (or something like that)  for both tablet and mobile phones so they are ignoring material design.
However if you want to use 320dp for mobile, you can add:

```
android:layout_width="320dp"
```

To your NavigationView.
In my own test, it made nav drawer width exactly same as "google play" app, but i prefer to stick with default material design settings.

Interestingly , if you use:

```
android:layout_width="280dp"
```

You will achieve exact same width with your current nav drawer width!

P.S. This material design guideline is just a template (a default and prefered value). you must choose best values for your app according to many factors. for example, if your navigation view items has long String so it's better to use 320dp for both mobile and tablet and vice versa. this is my opinion.